# How to downlaod a file (image, pdf,......) using talend

Tags: file, talend

I want to migrate Files (Attachments) from a FTP server to another server (Salesforce), to do that i am going to use talend. i have no clue which components to use and in which order in order to download the files (multiple formats but downloadable via a http link), and to insert them into salesforce database, i will be grateful if someone explains to me how to proceed (what are the components to use and how to relate them) ?

Comment: Try to use an `tftpget` or `tftpfilelist`, and `tsalesforceoutput`. you need to configure connection before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info provided, first you will obtain the files from the remote server, then load them as a BLOB into a database.

See the diagram for a typical FTP flow. The first component is a connection to the server which allows connection reuse.  The second component is optional, it allows you to get a count of file prior to your operations (you can use it later to make sure you retrieved all the files).  The third component (`tFTPGet`) is technically all you need.  This component actually grabs the files based on the file mask you set.  The final component `tFTPDelete` cleans up the remote directory.

[image]

Once you have the files locally see [this](https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Inserting+BLOB+or+CLOB+data+into+a+database) help link for information on how to insert files as BLOBs into a database.  You will have to tweak it for your SalesForce db.

Comment: I can see that you are new to StackOverflow.  If this answers your question please consider marking it as answered which will also help others to find this info.