# Insert comments in Jira with Talend

Tags: json, talend, jira-rest-api

During my searching, I would like advice about how to insert a comment in Jira issue via Talend Open Studio.

Here is my job :

[image]

So, I am trying to insert comment via Talend.
I use a tHttpRequest set like that :

[image]

uri is my string connection to get Jira account.

As it's a POST method, my header is `Content-Type | application/json`.

My post parameters are in a JSON file :

```
{
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "key": "TRL"
    },
    "summary": "A",
    "description": "B",
    "issuetype": {
        "name": "Task"
    },
    "labels": ["Webapp"],
    "reporter": {
        "name": "x.x"
    },
    "assignee": {
        "name": "x.x"
    }
},
"body": "TEST1",
"visibility": {
    "type": "role",
    "value": "Administrators"
}}
```

When I launch this job, the following error appears : 
[image]

As if the file of the response body was NULL, or maybe It's not the good manner to do the insert of the comment.

I clarify that with Insomnia([insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/)), the insertion of the comment works.

I try also the componant tRest but I don't succeed to link this one with tFileInputDelimited or tJIRAOutput.

Before to continue my work, I want to know if I am in the good direction ? Any clues ?

Thanks by advance,

Ale

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the tRest or tRestClient components. You can just send your JSON as "HTTP body" with these components.
On the JIRA side, you can get the necessary information here: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis

Assuming you're working with the on-premise JIRA, you'd use something like this:
*URL:* hostname + /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/comment
*HTTP Body:*

```
{
    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque eget venenatis elit. Duis eu justo eget augue iaculis fermentum. Sed semper quam laoreet nisi egestas at posuere augue semper.",
    "visibility": {
        "type": "role",
        "value": "Administrators"
    }
}
```

Don't forget about the [Authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-basic-authentication/)

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the advice !!! For you, logically, with these components, It works ?

Comment: Sure. It's just a matter of finding the right API method and calling that with a valid request.

Comment: I've build something similar about a year ago. We used the tRest component to create an issue and attach files.

Comment: Hi, OK ! I will post my solution after ... Thanks mate !

Comment: BTW, do you know if we could modify the created / updated date when we create the issue in Jira? Typically I have to transfer a history from Trello to Jira and they asked to me to maintain the original date of creation under Trello, is it possible? I saw a lot of post with the answer "NO!", could you confirm me?

Comment: Yes and No. Not via the REST API or manually. You can however use the [CSV Import] (https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-change-the-issue-creation-date-using-csv-import-779160699.html), work with scripting within JIRA or build your own Plugin that provides an API for that sort of thing.

Comment: An other question - I am alone on this project - I think it is possible to transfer attachment files from Trello to Jira with this rest API method : [attachments](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments) and thanks to this post [attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830814/how-to-downlaod-a-file-image-pdf-using-talend). Could you confirm ?

Comment: I haven't worked with the Trello API yet but you can add attachments to a JIRA issue with the method that  you mentioned.

Comment: Ok :) Thanks fellow !